# Table with two or more header rows

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I'm trying to create a table with two header rows in Word, formatted using one of the available Table Styles. The second row contains the headers, and the first row is "categories".

The table is meant to look like this (I drew this one in Excel for demonstration purposes):

[image]

When I create a table in Word, it first looks like this (notice the two header rows):

[image]

When I try to insert a row above the header row (to make a "categrory" header row), this pushes the existing headers down into the body of the table. Not good.

[image]

How do I make a table in Word with two or more header rows?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- Highlight the rows you want to act as the header.
- Head to the Table Tools (a) / Layout (b) tab.
- Click "Repeat Header Rows" (c).

[image]

Both the highlighted lines will now be considered a header:

[image]